# Loading URL from tableview

Tags: objective-c

I am creating an application in objective C whereby so far I have two Table view controllers:

View1: list of countries.

View2: table view with 3 rows as "History", "Cuisine" and "Sports".

Now i need help for view 3.

I want to load specific webpages on selecting rows from View2 which is again related to the country selected from view1.

Please let me know how should I proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a view controller with UIWebView, construct an URL request with the address of the web page and pass it to [UIWebView loadRequest:]. Push the view controller.

Comment: I have done that but now I am geeting an issue in main.m file which says:Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: If you run it in Debug configuration you should be able to see what line in your code caused the signal. Usually EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are trying to access a dangling pointer, i.e. a deallocated object.